# Create a hollow polymer structure and simulate its mechanical strength under compression

Tags: graphics, chemistry

I want to create a hollow cylinder structure surrounded by 13 cross-sections (structure details refer to https://elifesciences.org/articles/34695#s1). Each cross-section is connected by same spherical monomers (monomers are linked with spring). Apply a force on one end of the polymer, distances versus force curve can be obtained from another end of this polymer. Is this possible or any suggestions for realizing this via Mathematica?

Comment: For the static 1D case, each spring is compressed the same and has the full force. For the full 3D case,  model the monomers by point masses, keep one side fix apply the force to the other end and create the Lagrangian and solve the Lagrange equations. If you do not know the Lagrange formalism, you can do it with Netwon formalism.

Comment: This is certainly possible, but to get someone to help you you would be better off writing equations and including a sketch of your model here (as well as the link). Even better would be to show what you have tried in terms of coding.